# Constant Google Chrome problems (not crashing or freezing)

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome

I first noticed this problem with Netflix. I can't watch Netflix.com in Chrome for more than one day. After a fresh install of Chrome, I can watch Netflix endlessly in one day, but the next day all videos will say "Oops something went wrong" and suggest looking at chrome://components, or suggest clearing all browser history/cache (which doesn't fix anything).

The next symptom was that chrome couldn't connect to any website at all, giving a message of "Aw, snap!". Any other browser worked fine.

Steps I've taken that fail to resolve:
 1. Clearing all browser cache/history/temp files
 2. Killing chrome.exe to ensure a fresh process
 3. Renaming the AppData folder to old_Chrome so it generates new appdata

The only "step" that actually fixes chrome is to fully uninstall and reinstall it. But it always breaks again 1 to 3 days later. This problem has spanned across a clean OS reimaging I did last weekend (for other reasons).

Specs:
Windows 10.0.18362 Build 18362 (Pro), custom build tower, no 3rd party anti-virus, standard out-of-box windows firewall settings

Comment: Did you try another browser (Opera, Firefox, Edge)?

Comment: Paragraph 2: "Any other browser worked fine"